# How to see full array of values returned by countif (excel)

Tags: excel, countif

I am trying to do a countif for the number of times each value in a list appears in that list using =COUNTIF(T19:T39,T19:T39&"").

How do I see the full array that is output by this? Every time I try to calc the function it just returns 0. If I try to calculate as an array function (ctrl+shift+enter) I just get the value in the first entry of the array

Comment: You can't 'see' the output of an array within a single cell. What do you want to do with the values within this array? Simply see them? List them? Apply some additional, external function to them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`COUNTIF` syntax,

`=COUNTIF(range,criteria)`

In your formula, `=COUNTIF(T19:T39,T19:T39&"")` your range in actually `T19:T39` and criteria is also the same. But excel understands it as `=COUNTIF(T19:T39,T19&"")`. When you drag it down, the `T19` changes to `T20` and so on. You may have to drag the formula till `T39` to see the complete array